# IP посетителя

Tags: ip, php

Как я понял, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` должно выводить IP посетителя сайта. У меня же почему-то выводит IP самого сервера, на котором сайт. В чем может быть проблема? Может с настройками сервера что-то не так?

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас между пользователем и апачем стоит нгинХ, который работает как прокси для апача и при этом не передает ему данные о клиенте.  
Проверьте `$_SERVER["X-Real-IP"]` по умолчанию NginX пишет IP клиента в такой заголовок.  
Конфиг NginX можно подправить дописав в location в котором указано проксировать апач такую строку:  

    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

99% Nginx. ReinRaus прав.

Решение без лишних телодвижений:

```
/**
 * Определение настоящего IP адреса
 * @return string IP
 */
function real_ip(){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])){
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
    }
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Красота! Спасибо!